# asp.net 2.0 website deployment iis 6

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have developed an ASP.Net 2.0 website (Using VS 2008). The website uses sqlmembershipprovider and `authentication mode = "Forms"`.

When i deploy the site on my IIS 6 (Windows server 2003 R2) and try to browse the .aspx files it gives

```
"The webpage cannot be found HTTP 404"
```

and when i browse .html file in the same directory it gives

```
"You are not authorized to view this page You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."
```

I have given rights to almost every possible user on wwwroot folder and the website folder
 1. asp.net machine account (full control) 
2. IIS_WPG (Read & Execute, List Folder contents, Read) 
3. Internet Guest Account (IUSR_MachineName) (Full control) 
4. Network Service (Read & Execute, List Folder contents, Read) 
5. System (Full cotnrol)
 6. Users (Read & Execute, List Folder contents, Read) 
ASP.NET v2.0.50727 web service extensions are also allowed. In the directory security(authentication and access control) of my website i have only selected integrated windows authentication. default application pool is selected which has "network service" as application pool identity.. 
I am badly stuck and will be very grateful to you guys for helping me out... 
PS: I have searched a lot about my problem but couldn't find a working solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you set security settings wrong.

- If you only set `Integrated Windows authentication` in IIS then you should set your authentication method to Windows in your ASP.NET web app.

  `<authentication mode="Windows">`
- If you want to use Forms authentication then you should `Enable anonymous access` in IIS and should not check `Integrated Windows authentication`. On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) you can see this:

> Because forms authentication does not rely on IIS authentication, you should configure anonymous access for your application in IIS if you intend to use forms authentication in your ASP.NET application.

Comment: Thank you so much Iuviktor...<br> Is there any specific account in the enable anonymous access username??? if yes that what are the credential of that account?

Comment: If you have some own specific restricted account you can use it. Anyway there's a builtin account: IUSR_computername.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/50128/what-are-the-iusr-and-iwam-accounts-for-in-iis

Comment: i dont have the password of that acccount.

Comment: Check these article to find out your password: http://www.jasonsamuel.com/tag/iusr-password-reset/ or http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/passwords/how-can-i-check-the-password-of-the-iusr-and-iwam-local-accounts-on-a-machine-

Comment: Did you find a soution for your problems? Does your web application work?

Comment: sorry for replying so late.. i didnt have the access to the server... i tried the solution you suggested unchecked the integrated windows authentication and checked enable annonymous access and selected IUSR_MachineName... but nothing happend... it shows HTTP 404 .. any suggestion

Comment: 1) About a year ago I had the same problem, but that time the ASP.NET extension was not allowed. You said that is allowed now.
2) Is your site under "Default Web Site"? 3) If you look at the site Properties\Virtual Directory\Configuration\Mappings tab. Check if you can see .aspx extension there. 4) Check if Properties\ASP.NET tab is set to apropriate .NET version

Comment: 1)ASP.NET extensions are allowed. I even ran the aspnet_regiis -i command. 2)Yes it is under "Default Web site". 3)In the Mapping tab .aspx is there. 4) asp.net v2 is selected.

Comment: Does any other web application work in IIS? I made a basic .NET 2 web app in VS2010 and deployed in IIS. I created an application from it, set ASP.NET to 2.0, and now it runs.

Comment: (Used Win2003, IIS6 with enabled ASP.NET 2.0)

Comment: One more thing. Search the C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\LogFiles\W3SVC1 folder, and the last created file. In this you will find the file you wanted to access. Search the 404 string. Look at the numbers after it. What are they?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0f4ac79a-dc2b-4a5f-89c1-d57266aa6ffe.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Yes a reporting app is working absolutely fine on that same machine... with same IIS configuration as we discussed above. I ran the same (which is not working in IIS 6) application on my local machine (win 7 Pro x64 and IIS 7). It ran perfectly fine.